# Can we add items and quantity to a list through shovel approach and call that list outside a class?

Tags: ruby

Write a simple DSL for creating a shopping list. We should be able to specify the item name and quantity..
Something like.

```
sl = ShoppingList.new
sl.items do
  add("Toothpaste",2)
  add("Computer",1)
```

I am trying to add items and quantity both to a list, but facing trouble using shovel operation and also faced error to call this list outside the class. Can I list these items without using hash ?

```
class Array
 def initialize
   @list = []
   @total = 0
 end
 def add(items, quantity)
   if @list.include?(items) == false
     @list << items
   else @list.include?(items) == true
     @list
   end
   @total.each {|x| quantity += x }
 end
 def items(&block)
   @list.each(&block)
 end
 def total
   @total
 end
 def display
   @list
 end
end

sl = Array.new
sl.items do
 add('Toothpaste', 2)
 add('Computer', 1)
 add('Toothpaste', 3)
end
puts sl.list
puts sl.total
```

Expected Result :

s.list # => Should display list of items with quantity.

s.total # => Should display total of all quantities.

Comment: Shouldn't the class name be ShoppingList instead of Array?

Comment: Yes I have changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an attr_reader and attr_accessor missing in your code and the loop was not working (at least for me). With those [attr_reader and attr_accessor](https://mixandgo.com/learn/ruby_attr_accessor_attr_reader_attr_writer) you can get rid of at least two methods.

I wonder why you don't want to use a hash ..

Here's some working code, no hashes but an array of arrays, in my implementation counting the total numbers of items must be done at the end when all items are added.

```
class ShoppingList
 attr_reader :list
 attr_accessor :total

 def initialize
   @list = []
   @total = 0 
 end

 def add(items, quantity)
   if @list.include?(items) == false
     @list << [items, quantity]
   else
     @list
   end
 end

 def total_number_of_items
  quantities = list.map { |item| item[1] } 
  total = quantities.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x }
 end
end

sl = ShoppingList.new

sl.add('Toothpaste', 2)
sl.add('Computer', 1)
sl.add('Toothpaste', 3)

puts sl.list
puts sl.total_number_of_items
```

P.S. I renamed the method from Array to ShoppingList.

Comment: There is still a problem with the add method in my code, it is adding everything.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this was not the question, but isn't that super-easy with a hash?

```
class ShoppingList
 attr_reader :list

 def initialize
   @list = {}
 end

 def add(product_type, quantity)
    if list[product_type].nil?
      list[product_type] = quantity
    else 
      list[product_type] += quantity
    end
 end
end

sl = ShoppingList.new

sl.add('Toothpaste', 2)
sl.add('Computer', 1)
sl.add('Toothpaste', 3)

pp sl.list.inspect
pp sl.list.keys.inspect
pp sl.list.values.inspect
```

Result:

```
"{\"Toothpaste\"=>5, \"Computer\"=>1}"
"[\"Toothpaste\", \"Computer\"]"
"[5, 1]"
```

Comment: Yes Christian, I had done this with hash and wanted to implement above approach
 too, to check out different possibilities. But as you pointed out some mistakes in my code, that really helped me to understand some mistakes in my programming techniques. Glad you helped.

Comment: Glad I could help you.

Comment: This should be the answer. The other code is not working as expected.